# could not convert string to float

Tags: python, string, csv

I am very new to python and I only need it so I analyse some data for bio.
Please help on How I can fix the error below,
`could not convert string to float`
I am trying to plot (Time, Distance)

Here is some sample data:

```
Nematode No.    1           1              2          2
No. of jumps    Time (sec)  Distance (mm)    Time        Distance
1              0.195781141  0.893988392    1.25388    0.56569
2              2.386623538  1.073359412    3.5848484  1.55656
3              2.915538343  1.227371636    4.284848   2.34454545
4              4.993603286  0.653631116    6.4545454  3.65445
5              8.002735854  0.986036142    2.35554    0.2548545
6             10.84267517   0.939671599    4.245454   0.5484848
```

**My code** (yet)

```
from mmap import mmap,ACCESS_READ

from xlrd import open_workbook
from pylab import *
from xlrd import open_workbook,XL_CELL_TEXT
import csv
from scipy import stats

values = csv.reader(open('simple.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',',skipinitialspace=True)

for column in values:
    print column[1],column[2]

Time = column[1]
Distance = column[2]

plot(Time,Distance)
show()
```

Comment: Either your sample data or your code is off, your test data has delimiter space, while the code requires comma, and your code is accessing columns 2 and 3 while the sample data only has 2 columns.

Comment: Hello...what do you mean its accessing columns 2 and 3?? How do I change that??

Comment: I am getting this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/jkjk", line 29, in <module>
    plot(Time, Distance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2817, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 3997, in plot
    self.add_line(line)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 1507, in add_line
    
  
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: The column index is zero based, that is, `column[0]` is the first column, not `column[1]`.

Comment: Still not working :O What do u mean that my code might be off?

Comment: Did you look at @JFSebastian's answer below? The first line doesn't contain float values, so it needs to be skipped.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.loadtxt("simple.csv", skiprows=1, unpack=True)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

First row contains your column names and can't be converted to floats because they aren't numbers to begin with so you should skip the first row when trying to plot the data.

For the updated data: skip the first 2 rows with headers and plot the 2nd, 3rd columns:

```
x, y = np.loadtxt("simple.csv", skiprows=2, usecols=[1, 2], unpack=True)
```

Comment: I changed it but it looks weird when I copy pasted it hopefully it makes sense....So basically my first row is nematode no and my first column is no of jumps Then for the next columns I have time and distance for each nematode

Comment: Please help me write a code that could plot seperate time and distance graphs for each nematode

Comment: Oh no its giving me new error: File "C:/Python27/dsds", line 4, in <module>
    x, y = np.loadtxt("simple.csv", skiprows=2, usecols=[1, 2], unpack=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 803, in loadtxt
    vals = [vals[i] for i in usecols]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Mel19: the code works for the data from the question. Check that simple.csv has at least 3 columns.

Comment: Actually it has 20 columns because I did measurements on 10 nematodes...what shud I do??

Comment: @Mel19: Provide **actual** input data (the first few lines might be enough if all lines have the same number of columns). Provide **actual** code that you use (exactly 5 lines of code as shown in my answer). Provide **actual** error/traceback that you get.